# How to save vpn password on computer using powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, vpn, regedit

This is the code I use

```
Add-VpnConnection -Name 'vpn' -ServerAddress 'vpn.server.com'
rasdial 'vpn' 'username' 'password'
```

When the VPN disconnects and reconnects, it asks the client to enter the vpn password,

I want a way to bypass asking client for the password

[image]

Comment: Your missing `-RememberCredential` [Proper research is required](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/vpnclient/add-vpnconnection?view=windowsserver2022-ps)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `-RememberCredential` parameter when creating the VPN connection as indicated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/vpnclient/add-vpnconnection?source=recommendations&view=windowsserver2022-ps):

> -RememberCredential
>
> Indicates that the credentials supplied at the time of first successful connection are stored in the cache.

Your cmdlet should be:

```ps
Add-VpnConnection -Name 'vpn' -ServerAddress 'vpn.server.com' -RememberCredential
```

The first time you connect, you will be asked for the username and password. Next time you connect, it will remember them and connect without asking for the username and password.

Comment: If no one sends a direct solution within an hour without typing in the password the first time, I'll give you 3 points (: